# DataMapper: multiple has-and-belongs-to-many relationships between the same models?

Tags: ruby, orm, associations, datamapper, relationship

How can I set up multiple relationships of the `has n, :through => Resource` type between the same models with DataMapper?

For instance, in a news CMS I would have something like this:

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  has n, :written_articles, 'Article', :through => Resource
  has n, :edited_articles, 'Article', :through => Resource

  property :name, String # etc.
end

class Article
  include DataMapper::Resource

  has n, :authors, 'User', :through => Resource
  has n, :editors, 'User', :through => Resource

  property :title, String # etc.
end
```

However, this doesn't work. The database just has one relationship table in which both an author and editor must be specified for each relation, which doesn't even make sense.

How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it using anonymous Resource - the code you provided will create single relational model, UserArticle, that is unable to handle two many-to-many relations (at least automatically). You would need to create a separate explicit relational model, e.g ArticleEditor, to handle this.

```
class ArticleEditor
  include DataMapper::Resource

  belongs_to :article,   :key => true
  belongs_to :user, :key => true
end
```

and in your models state

```
 has n, :article_editors
 has n, :editors (or :edited_articles), :through => :article_editors
```